# #{notes.revise.fieldValues[v.count].textValue} throws javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

Tags: jsf, el, setter

I'm having an error in which it says "javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation". I'm suspecting it has something to do with my EL expression syntax?

```
<p:inputText id="custom_${notes.key}_${v.count}"
   value="#{notes.revise.fieldValues[v.count].textValue}"
   maxlength="1000"
   styleClass="prop-custom-text" />
```

Here is the error message:

```
17:52:27,606 SEVERE [org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler] (default task-7) FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during processing JSF ajax request. Error page '/WEB-INF/error.xhtml' will be shown.: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
    at com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:168) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:294) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:832) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:749) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1290) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1290) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:577) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:381) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:266) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60) [primefaces-5.1.jar:5.1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1252) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at com.dialanote.servlet.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:53) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's the given EL expression? It looks OK as it's not a read only expression. This exception is typical on read only expressions such as `#{foo ? bar : baz}` or `#{foo.getBar()}`. But the one you have is absolutely writable. A MCVE would be helpful in nailing down the cause. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Answer (score 0):

Ooops looks like I found my mistake! When I pasted my code here, I edited it a bit for easy reading, didn't realized that I already fixed it here haha.

Here's what it looks like originally. The culprit is the white space after the EL expression.

```
<p:inputText 
   id="custom_${notes.key}_${v.count}" value="#{notes.revise.fieldValues[v.count].textValue} "
   maxlength="1000" styleClass="prop-custom-text" />
```